# Flutter writeAsBytes from dart:io library returns PathNotFoundException

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the following function in flutter:

```
Future<File> getFile(String fileName) async {
  final appDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final appPath = appDir.path;
  final fileOnDevice = File('$appPath/$fileName');
  final rawAssetFile = await rootBundle.load(fileName);
  final rawBytes = rawAssetFile.buffer.asUint8List();
  await fileOnDevice.writeAsBytes(rawBytes, flush: true);
  return fileOnDevice;
}
```

But somehow i keep getting this error, failed PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/352527E9-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-DCFXXXXXXXXX/Library/Caches/assets/

The function is called by final dataFile = await getFile('assets/sample.txt');

Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help is appreciated!

This is my flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64, locale en-SG)
• Flutter version 3.7.0 on channel stable at /Users/xaviertoh/Documents/Flutter/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision b06b8b2710 (3 weeks ago), 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
• Engine revision b24591ed32
• Dart version 2.19.0
• DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/xaviertoh/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.0)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone (mobile) • 00008020-000D05313C02002E • ios            • iOS 13.5 17F75
• macOS (desktop) • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.1 22C65
darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.77

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

Thank you for reading!

Things i have tried:

1. I have confirmed that my file name is correct in the assets folder and i also tried running this code in various locations in the code such as in a widget and also in main() just to test it out.
2. I also tried running flutter in xcode and visual studio code.
3. Also tried to run the code in android emulator and also on iPhone physical device.

Answer (score 0):

The `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Library/Caches/assets/` directory must already exist. `File.writeAsBytes` won't automatically create parent directories for you.

You can do that step by first doing:

```dart
await fileOnDevice.parent.create(recursive: true);
```